# Diving into Python sequences: analyze an access.log

Tags: python, beginner, parsing, logging

As a first little Python exercise, I wrote an analyzer/summarizer for my nginx accesslogs. The code works fine but I'm not sure if I used the different types of sequences properly or made some other stupid things which could lead to bugs etc.

---

Steps:

1. read in access.log and heavily poke around to fetch the wanted data (requests, IPs and user agents till now)
2. sum the occurrences
3. sort the sums desc and write the top x sums into a file

---

Example generalized log (I don't know if that's helpful):

```
1.1.1.1 - - [21/Feb/2014:06:35:45 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 112 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
1.1.1.1 - - [21/Feb/2014:06:35:45 +0100] "GET /blog.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3663 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
2.2.2.2 - - [21/Feb/2014:06:52:04 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
2.2.2.2 - - [21/Feb/2014:06:52:04 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
3.3.3.3 - - [21/Feb/2014:06:58:14 +0100] "/" 200 1664 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117"
4.4.4.4 - - [21/Feb/2014:07:22:03 +0100] "/" 200 1664 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117"
5.5.5.5 - - [21/Feb/2014:07:32:48 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
5.5.5.5 - - [21/Feb/2014:07:32:48 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
6.6.6.6 - - [21/Feb/2014:08:13:01 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
6.6.6.6 - - [21/Feb/2014:08:13:01 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
7.7.7.7 - - [21/Feb/2014:08:51:25 +0100] "GET /main.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3681 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; Q312461)"
7.7.7.7 - - [21/Feb/2014:08:51:34 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
7.7.7.7 - - [21/Feb/2014:08:51:48 +0100] "GET /tag/php.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4673 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; Q312461)"
8.8.8.8 - - [21/Feb/2014:08:53:43 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
8.8.8.8 - - [21/Feb/2014:08:53:43 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
9.9.9.9 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:18:40 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
9.9.9.9 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:18:40 +0100] "GET /main HTTP/1.1" 200 3681 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117"
9.9.9.9 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:18:41 +0100] "GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117"
9.9.9.9 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:18:42 +0100] "GET /pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117"
10.10.10.10 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:21:29 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
10.10.10.10 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:21:29 +0100] "GET /main.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3681 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117"
10.10.10.10 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:21:30 +0100] "GET /about.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2832 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117"
10.10.10.10 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:21:30 +0100] "GET /tag/nginx.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3295 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117"
10.10.10.10 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:21:31 +0100] "GET /how-to-setup.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2637 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117"
1.1.1.1 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:27:27 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 112 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
1.1.1.1 - - [21/Feb/2014:09:27:27 +0100] "GET /tag/tor.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2041 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
5.5.5.5 - - [21/Feb/2014:10:14:37 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
5.5.5.5 - - [21/Feb/2014:10:14:37 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
8.8.8.8 - - [21/Feb/2014:10:55:19 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
8.8.8.8 - - [21/Feb/2014:10:55:19 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
1.1.1.1 - - [21/Feb/2014:11:19:05 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 112 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
1.1.1.1 - - [21/Feb/2014:11:19:06 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 112 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
1.1.1.1 - - [21/Feb/2014:11:19:06 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3649 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
6.6.6.6 - - [21/Feb/2014:12:16:14 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
6.6.6.6 - - [21/Feb/2014:12:16:15 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
5.5.5.5 - - [21/Feb/2014:14:17:52 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
5.5.5.5 - - [21/Feb/2014:14:17:52 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
6.6.6.6 - - [21/Feb/2014:14:58:04 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
6.6.6.6 - - [21/Feb/2014:14:58:04 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
5.5.5.5 - - [21/Feb/2014:15:38:46 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
5.5.5.5 - - [21/Feb/2014:15:38:47 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
2.2.2.2 - - [21/Feb/2014:18:20:36 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
2.2.2.2 - - [21/Feb/2014:18:20:37 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
5.5.5.5 - - [21/Feb/2014:19:42:00 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
5.5.5.5 - - [21/Feb/2014:19:42:00 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
2.2.2.2 - - [21/Feb/2014:20:22:13 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
2.2.2.2 - - [21/Feb/2014:20:22:13 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
6.6.6.6 - - [21/Feb/2014:21:02:55 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
6.6.6.6 - - [21/Feb/2014:21:02:55 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
8.8.8.8 - - [22/Feb/2014:01:05:37 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
8.8.8.8 - - [22/Feb/2014:01:05:38 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
8.8.8.8 - - [22/Feb/2014:04:28:10 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
8.8.8.8 - - [22/Feb/2014:04:28:10 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
2.2.2.2 - - [22/Feb/2014:05:49:34 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
2.2.2.2 - - [22/Feb/2014:05:49:34 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
5.5.5.5 - - [22/Feb/2014:06:29:47 +0100] "GET /main/rss HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Motorola"
5.5.5.5 - - [22/Feb/2014:06:29:47 +0100] "GET /feed/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Motorola"
```

---

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os.path


class LogAnalyzer():
    """ Parses and summarizes nginx logfiles """

    def __init__(self, readfile, writefile, topcount=5):
        """ Initializing """
        self.summary = {
            "requests": {},
            "ips": {},
            "useragents": {}
        }

        self.topcount = topcount

        self.reafile = readfile
        self.writefile = writefile

    def analyze(self):
        """ Reads and splits the access-log into our dictionary """
        #is file?
        if not os.path.isfile(self.reafile):
            print(self.reafile, "does not exist! exiting")
            exit(1)

        log = open(self.reafile, 'r')
        lines = log.readlines()
        log.close()
        loglist = []

        for s in lines:
            line = s.strip()
            tmp = line.split(' ')
            ip = tmp[0]

            #not the finest way...get indices of double quotes
            doublequotes = LogAnalyzer.find_chars(line, '"')

            #get the starting/ending indices of request & useragents by their quotes
            request_start = doublequotes[0]+1
            request_end = doublequotes[1]
            useragent_start = doublequotes[4]+1
            useragent_end = doublequotes[5]

            request = line[request_start:request_end]
            useragent = line[useragent_start:useragent_end]

            #writing a dictionary per line into a list...huh...dunno
            loglist.append({
                "ip": ip,
                "request": request,
                "useragent": useragent
            })

        self.summarize(loglist)
        self.write_summary()

    def summarize(self, cols):
        """ count occurences """
        for col in cols:
            if not col['request'] in self.summary['requests']:
                self.summary['requests'][col['request']] = 0
            self.summary['requests'][col['request']] += 1

            if not col['ip'] in self.summary['ips']:
                self.summary['ips'][col['ip']] = 0
            self.summary['ips'][col['ip']] += 1

            if not col['useragent'] in self.summary['useragents']:
                self.summary['useragents'][col['useragent']] = 0
            self.summary['useragents'][col['useragent']] += 1

    def write_summary(self):
        """ sorts and writes occurences into file """
        summary = open(self.writefile, 'w')
        summary.write("Log summary\n")
        for key in self.summary:
            list = sorted(self.summary[key].items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
            list = list[:self.topcount]
            summary.write("\nTop "+key+":\n")
            for l in list:
                summary.write(l[0]+": "+str(l[1])+" times\n")
        summary.close()

    @staticmethod
    def find_chars(string, char):
        """ returns a list of all indices of char inside string """
        return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(string) if ltr == char]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = './access.log'
    summaryfile = './access_summary.log'
    summary = LogAnalyzer(logfile, summaryfile, 5)
    summary.analyze()
```

---

Notes:

Regex: I know it may would be "better" if I simply used regular expressions, but:

1. I really have problems creating the patterns .
2. I wanted to get some experiences with Python's sequence functions. But that leads to the ugly part in the analyze-function, because I need

   - split-function with whitespaces for dividing each line into parts (I may want to fetch the date-times and status codes as well later)
   - for-loop to find out the request and user agent, because they are embedded in double-quotes and usually contain whitespaces.

Could that be made better? Are there some other things to improve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find your `find_chars()` method amusingly creative.  I'll comment on the big picture instead.

- **Class design:** Passing all the parameters into the constructor makes the class less versatile.  Those parameters don't need to be part of the object's state.  Consider this outline instead:

  ```
  class LogAnalyzer():
      def __init__(self):
          self.summary = …

      def analyze(self, logfile):
          …

      def summarize(self, topcount=5):
          …
  ```

  Then you have the flexibility to summarize several log files at once:

  ```
  analysis = LogAnalyzer()
  analysis.analyze('access_log.0')
  analysis.analyze('access_log.1')
  analysis.analyze('access_log.2')
  print(analysis.summarize('access_summary.txt'))
  ```

  Consider making it the caller's responsibility to write the result to a file.  I don't think that it's essential to the business of log analysis.
- Take advantage of [**`collections.Counter`**](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).
- Open files using **`with` blocks**.  Then you never have to worry about closing them.
- **Avoid reading everything into memory at once.**  Read a line at a time, use it to update the cumulative statistics, and don't hold on to `lines`.  If possible, avoid keeping `loglist` as well.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

class LogAnalyzer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.linecount = 0
        self.counters = defaultdict(Counter)

    def analyze(self, logfile):
        with open(logfile) as f:
            for line in f:
                self._update(**self._parse(line))

    def summarize(self, topcount=5):
        …

    @staticmethod
    def _parse(line):
        …
        return {'ip': …, 'request': …, 'useragent': … }

    def _update(self, **kwargs):
        self.linecount += 1
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.counters[key][value] += 1
```

Comment: the find_chars-body is taken from a stackoverflow-question ;)

Comment: thanks for your tips, particularly the collections.Counter sounds quite helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Everything that @200_success wrote was good advice. As for the actual parsing of the file, there is actually a better way:

```
    with open(logfile, "rb") as f:
        for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '):
            self._update(**self._parse(line))
```

Python's csv module contains code the read CSV files, but you can also use it to read files with a similar format, such as this one. This uses spaces instead of commas to seperate the values, but follows the same quoting rules as CSV. The code above will get each line as list of the columns like this:

```
['1.1.1.1', '-', '-', '[21/Feb/2014:06:35:45', '+0100]', 'GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1', '200', '112', '-', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)']
```

Thus all the hard working of parsing is already done, you should be able to easily pull the information you want.